# Trim spaces after string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

After I fetch data from SQLite, in this example I have city and state.  "San Jose  " and "CA" respectively. let's call them NSString *city and *state.

When I put them on a label like so...

```
Label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",city,state];
```

I get... "San Jose          , CA" before of all the white spaces from the database.  How can I get rid of those spaces.  I am only familiar with NSMakeRange and know only how to trim it to a certain length.  Thanks for your help in advance.  The editor is not really showing all the spaces but it has like 10 white spaces after san jose.

Comment: Did you even LOOK at the NSString spec before posting???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[city stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

You can do the same with state ofcourse.